# Sending through variables in `res.render` that are conditionally empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to send through multiple variables into a `res.render` but I'm unsure of how to do it without an undefined error. Either one or the other will have an object to pass through but never both at the same time. Here's my current code that will give an undefined error.

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
if (req.query.search) {
    const search = req.query.search
    const regex = new RegExp(search, 'i')
    const searchedblogposts = await BlogPost.find({title: {$regex: regex}})
    console.log(searchedblogposts)
} else {
    const blogposts = await BlogPost.find({})
}

res.render('index', {
    blogposts,
    searchedblogposts
    })
})
```

Comment: what exactly is the error you're seeing?

Comment: Either blogposts is not defined or searchedblogposts is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is because one of `blogPosts` or `searchBlogPosts` remains undefined at any point of time and you're passing both in `res.render` . What you can do is this:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
let blogPosts;
if (req.query.search) {
    const search = req.query.search
    const regex = new RegExp(search, 'i')
    blogPosts = await BlogPost.find({title: {$regex: regex}})
} else {
    blogposts = await BlogPost.find({})
}

res.render('index', {
    blogposts,
    })
})
```

OR this:

```
 app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

const blogPosts = req.query.search? await BlogPost.find({title: {$regex: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i')}}) 
: await BlogPost.find({})
    
    res.render('index', {
        blogposts,
        })
    })
```

Comment: That way makes a lot more sense! I got that it wasn't able down undefined variables but I wasn't too sure how to get around that but this way is 10x more simple and I don't know how I didn't come to that myself. Thank you very much!